# IE8 and Primefaces p:selectOneMenu misbehave when having a lots of p:selectOneMenu in a form

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

First of all, I want to apologize for the long code I post, they are very simple, it is just a `p:selectOneMenu` that repeat 17 times (that why it is long). **The problem that I experience is that if I have too many `p:selectOneMenu` in a form, the `selectOneMenu` bugged out and wont drop down when the user click on it (unless I spam click on the `selectOneMenu`)**, the list will not drop down. What is very bizarre is that if it is only 1 or 2 `selectOneMenu` then it work fine (this is why I post code that display 17 drop down list). This only happen in IE8. This work fine is IE6,7 FF, Chrome.

**Once again: apologize for the long code**

**EDIT1: I just edit my code to add more entries to `foodList` to my managed bean. This is crucial in in order to replicate my issues**

```
<div id="MainWrapper">
    <h:form id="myForm" styleClass="mainForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="columnStyle,columnStyle">
            <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                Select Food1:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food1" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood1"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood1" for="food1"/>

                Select Food2:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food2" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood2"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood" for="food2"/>

                Select Food3:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food3" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood3"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood3" for="food3"/>

                Select Food4:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food4" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood4"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood4" for="food4"/>

                Select Food5:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food5" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood5"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood5" for="food5"/>

                Select Food6:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food6" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood6"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood6" for="food6"/>

                Select Food7:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food7" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood7"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood7" for="food7"/>

                Select Food8:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food8" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood8"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood8" for="food8"/>

                Select Food9:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food9" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood9"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood9" for="food9"/>

                Select Food10:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food10" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood10"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood10" for="food10"/>

                Select Food11:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food11" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood11"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood11" for="food11"/>

                Select Food12:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food12" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood12"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood12" for="food12"/>

                Select Food13:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food13" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood13"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood13" for="food13"/>

                Select Food14:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food14" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood14"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood14" for="food14"/>

                Select Food15:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food15" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood15"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood15" for="food15"/>

                Select Food16:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food16" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood16"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood16" for="food16"/>

                Select Food17:
                <p:selectOneMenu id="food17" required="true" value="#{viewBean.selectedFood}"
                                    styleClass="dropdown-width">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select One" itemValue=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{viewBean.foodList}"/>
                    <p:ajax update=":myForm:errorFood17"/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
                <p:message id="errorFood17" for="food17"/>
            </h:panelGrid>
            There is supposed to be another table here
        </h:panelGrid>
        <p:commandButton value="submit" update="myForm"/>
    </h:form>
</div>
```

Managed Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {

    private List<String> foodList;
    private String selectedFood;

    public ViewBean() {
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        foodList = new ArrayList<String>();
        foodList.add("Pizza");
        foodList.add("Pasta");
        foodList.add("Hamburger");
        foodList.add("Hot Dog");
        foodList.add("Spring Roll");
        foodList.add("Grill Fish");
        foodList.add("Chips");
        foodList.add("Ramen");
    }
    //setter, getter
}
```

Here is my CSS.

```
body{
    background-color: #EBEAE3;
    font-family: Trebuchet;
    margin: 0;
}

#MainWrapper{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1100px;
    background-color: white;
}

.columnStyle{
    vertical-align: top;
}

.mainForm{
    margin-left: 68px;
}

.dropdown-width{
    width: 400px;
}

.ui-widget {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

td .ui-selectonemenu {
    display:block;
}
```

I have spent lots of time debugging this, but the fact that it bug out when there are many `selectOneMenu` and work fine when there are 1 or 2 `selectOneMenu` just rack my brain out.
Here is my doctype

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in IE9 set to IE8 mode (which is to my experience pretty reliable in reproducing IE8 specific bugs). I unfortunately don't have a real IE8 on this machine. Do you have more in your view or CSS? What's the doctype? The symptoms which you describe indicate a z-index or probably haslayout related issue.

Comment: Hi BalusC, I have posted my doctype on my post. I have tried with `<!DOCTYPE html>`, but it still does not work. I use http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage to test different version of IE, unfortunately I dont have vista or window 7 to load IE9 to test. I spend time to isolate the problem, so the code I post are it.

Comment: Did you test in a real IE8? The IETester is handy but not 100% reliable. The compliance mode of IE9 is much more reliable.

Comment: I did test with real IE8, BalusC. It happen the same way. I even create a brand new project, and download the codes that I posted above and still able to recreate the problem. I am reading up on haslayout issue now. Hope it will shed some light.

Comment: I know that some browsers Bug Out when your using fonts in `<select>` boxes. Are you styling the font?

Comment: @user1090389: there is very limited styling on the font of the `select`. I also try to take the font styling out, but it does not fix the issue.

Comment: @BalusC: I figure out why you cannot replicate my issue. My `foodList` have a lots more entries than what I posted. So in my managed bean, if my `foodList` have only 3 entries like what I posted, then it is fine, but if I have about 10 foods, then I start seeing the problem. If you can give it one more try and see if u can replicate the issue on your end, I would greatly greatly appreciate it. (NOTE: it is important that you have many selectOneMenu, otherwise you cannot replicate this issue. I have posted 17 selectOneMenu above). Please let me know if you still cant replicate it

Comment: I installed IETester and I have reproduced it in its IE8 tab. It requires a tripleclick to get the dropdown list to be shown. Given the fact that I couldn't reproduce it in IE9 on IE8 mode, the root cause must be in the JS event handling. I also noticed that IETester crashed after having the tab open for a few minutes. This indicates an infinite recursion somewhere in the JS code. I am pretty familiar with JS, but not with internals of jQuery. I peeked in the PF JS source which is using lot of jQuery, but I couldn't immediately find any possible causes. I would report it as a bug to PF guys.

Comment: @BalusC: I have post this problem in the primefaces forum http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=17662 And I also file a bug report at http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3352 . If you have some times, I would greatly appreciated if you can provide some comment to the discussion?

Comment: @BalusC:I know this has been a while, but today I re-look at this issue, and i find out this, if I run this as `localhost` like `http://localhost:8080/TestPF`, but if I run it as `http://my-full-computer-name-or-my-internal-ip:8080/TestPF`, then the problem go away. I find this odd, so I just want to note you just in case this spark a lead somewhere. Thank you for all your help, BalusC.

Comment: Well, I'd expect it to happen the other way round. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325272/jsf-2-application-ui-formatting-messed-up-on-ie-when-using-ip-address-instead-of/7325590#7325590 But that would mean that this problem won't occur on "live" environment, right?

Comment: ohhh wow, this is neat to know. I honestly do know if this is issue will happen in the live environment. We have not deploy it yet. but I hope it wont (figure cross :D) thank you very much BalusC

Answer (score 6):

I have the same problem. Tested on Primefaces 3.0.RC1 and 3.1 on Mojarra 2.1.3 (FCS b02)

I did not find a solution, but I did found 3 workarounds:

1) Change your layout so the dropdowns are not over each other (or over other components)

2) Add IE 7 Compatibility to as a tag to your page. The following statement has to be above you  tag. (because it must be the first meta tag)

> ```
> <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
> ```

3) Be sure to always show a vertical scrollbar. 
To do this you can add the following to your CSS3 stylesheet:

```
body {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Or CSS2:

```
body {
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

I find it strange how some of these workarounds work, but they do. I myself went for option 3.

I hope there will be a fix soon.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by dropdowns being not over other components (z-index?) but the workaround with scroll is working for me. As for now, the issues with dropdowns seems to be solved. It needs some tests, but hopefully it's gone. It seems to be the problem with quite straightforward tricks used by Primefaces when calculating the size of elements before display: using containers with visibility: hidden and not display: none.

Comment: The CSS solution worked for me on IE 8.0.7601.17514. Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

we have also this problem in IE7, It requires a tripleclick to get the dropdown list to be shown. 
unbelievable solution aehh workarround: insert a

```
<p:confirmDialog> 
</p:confirmDialog>
```

in the site, where selectOneMenu has been used :-) It works.

Comment: I have reported the issue here. If you can provide comment, or vote, that would be awesome. Thank you. http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3352

Comment: @Stefan: I would like to vote this answer up ten times. I can't believe it worked. None of the other suggestions listed above did, but adding a blank p:confirmDialog solved the problem. It was even simpler, I just added: <p:confirmDialog />. You are a hero.