# Primefaces: autocomplete panel often not displayed in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, autocomplete, primefaces, frame

We have **PrimeFaces 3.4** application that was working very fine until it was tested under **firefox**. However, after going to test, the problems have arised:

- Application will be launched in IE only (IE 9)
- Application is launched inside **frameset**

We are using `p:autocomplete` in many places, that includes dialogs. The panels for those autocompletes are usually not displayed after click when:

- Running inside frameset (rarely happens in normal mode)
- IE developers tools are closed (rarely happens when they are opened, making the bug hard to debug)
- The browser window is not maximized

The last thing is the key from our observations. The solution is to either maximize browser (which can work because we have big screens) or to zoom out the content. Therefore, I suspect that it's the issue with calculating the position where the autocomplete panel must be displayed. The algorithm must take into account several conditions, such as if the parent is positioned (dialog: position fixed), if there is scroll, whan is the offset - here the frames could mess up some things.

However, debugging is hardly an option, first because there is no official non-minimized primefaces.js, second because opening the IE developers tools somehow stops the error from occuring.

Under those circumstances, I ask how the autocomplete can behave such way, and how it can be affected by any of the elements of the puzzle: frameset, dialog, IE development tools?

Comment: What you're saying about the developer tools suggests that there are stray `console.log()` calls in the code.  Those can cause problems when the developer console is not open.

Comment: but this is not the case with console, and anyway, screen maximization without ie dev tools is more efficient in 'fighting' the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related with: [IE8 and Primefaces p:selectOneMenu misbehave when having a lots of p:selectOneMenu in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856704/ie8-and-primefaces-pselectonemenu-misbehave-when-having-a-lots-of-pselectoneme)

The problem is that **PrimeFaces** relies on `visibility:hidden` to make a lot of dimension calculations. When the invisible components were out of page bounds, IE wasn't calculating dimensions as supposed. I haven't gone into details of PrimeFaces rendering engine, but simply activating **always** scroll solved the problem:

```
body { overflow-y:scroll; }
```

This answers the question why the problem was often seen when the frameset was used (less place) or why maximizing browser was helping.